# Python Scrapy , how to define a pipeline for an item?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl different sites, for each site I have an Item (different information is extracted)

Well, for example I have a generic pipeline (most of information is the same) but now I am crawling some google search response and the pipeline must be different.

For example:

`GenericItem` uses `GenericPipeline`

But the `GoogleItem` uses `GoogleItemPipeline`, but when the spider is crawling it tries to use `GenericPipeline` instead of `GoogleItemPipeline`....how can I specify which pipeline Google spider must use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now only one way - check Item type in pipeline and process it or return "as is"

*pipelines.py*:

```
from grabbers.items import FeedItem

class StoreFeedPost(object):

    def process_item(self, domain, item):
        if isinstance(item, FeedItem):
            #process it...

        return item
```

*items.py*:

```
from scrapy.item import ScrapedItem

class FeedItem(ScrapedItem):
    pass
```